# how to start semi circle donut chart angle from respective position in highchart?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

How can i make the  start angle and end angle in the highchart to fixed points. As i have tried with below code. Its working but not as expected.

`plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                distance: -50,
                style: {
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    color: 'white'
                }
            },
             slicedOffset: 45,
            startAngle: -120,
           endAngle: 120,
            center: ['50%', '50%'],
            size: '110%'
        }
    },`

Output should be like in the below image . Please check with the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fekkyDev/bxdn3t4o/2/)

Thank you

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting

```
plotOptions: {
    pie: {
       startAngle: -55,
       endAngle: 230,
       ...
    }
}
```

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    plotBackgroundColor: null,
    plotBorderWidth: 0,
    plotShadow: false
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Browser<br>shares<br>2017',
    align: 'center',
    verticalAlign: 'middle',
    y: -5,
    x: -110
  },
  tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    pie: {
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        distance: -50,
        style: {
          fontWeight: 'bold',
          color: 'white'
        }
      },
      slicedOffset: 45,
      startAngle: -55,
      endAngle: 230,
      center: ['50%', '50%'],
      size: '110%'
    }
  },
  series: [{
    type: 'pie',
    name: 'Browser share',
    innerSize: '50%',
    data: [
      ['Chrome', 58.9],
      ['Firefox', 13.29],
      ['Internet Explorer', 13],
      ['Edge', 3.78],
      ['Safari', 3.42],
      {
        name: 'Other',
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: false
        }
      }
    ]
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```